# Google Drive API: can't read doc owned by other user

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, gspread

I'm trying to read some Google Doc using the `gspread` client (Python).

I have instanciated a `gspread.Client` using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` and an oauth token for my account.

I tried opening two different files, only the first one (file that I own) can be read this way.

The second file (which is shared with me through a group and I can open in the web app) fails to be read:

```
>>> gc.open_by_key("171b...") # I created this file
<Spreadsheet ...>
>>> gc.open_by_key("1ehE...") # This file is shared with me
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 404, 'message': 'Requested entity was not found.', 'status': 'NOT_FOUND'}
```

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: defile shared with you.  Do a file.list can you see the file?

Comment: @DaImTo If I do a `gc.list_spreadsheet_files()` I see only 3 files that I own, I don't see all the files that I have access to (through a group) and that I can access using the API

Comment: I am assuming the files are under your "Shared with me" tab, can you try to see if creating a shortcut of it to your "My Drive" allows it to be searchable?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved after requiring the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` when authenticating the user.